# QBRTCStatsReportCallback interface is not getting in quickblox

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox-android

I am integrating `QuickBlox` framework in my project. I have import all the files of `WebRTC` for video calling functionality but my problem is i am not getting `QBRTCStatsReportCallback` interface file in my project.

This is my code:

[image]